# Getting 1 column out of Three columns from Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

In my [Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/39258)

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content,
(
  SELECT 
  EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 1), 
  EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 2), 
  EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 3)
) AS ex
FROM `docs` a
```

I want it to return the Subquery values separated by commas like that

```
id rev content ex
1  1   ....... 1,1,0
```

But i keep getting `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`, How can I deal with this problem overall when I want to return multiple column values in a single column from a Subquery?

What I get is the `error` I mentioned but what i want to get is

```
id  rev     content                                              ex
1   1       The earth is flat                                    1,1,0
1   2       The earth is flat and rests on a bull's horn         1,1,0
1   3       The earth is like a ball.                            1,1,0
2   1       One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin    1,1,0
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question as text*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want `CONCAT`:

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/39267/0)

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content,
       CONCAT(CAST(EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 1) as char(1)),',',
              CAST(EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 2) as char(1)),',',
              CAST(EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `docs` WHERE id = 3) as char(1))
       ) AS ex
FROM `docs` a
```

Comment: Yes, Almost my Queries returns more than a Column in a Subquery, So I always wanted to know how to deal with this problem, Seems `CONCAT` is the solution.

Comment: Can it be used using `JOIN` instead of `CONCAT`? giving each query a name, and making it w/ith its specific column in the main query.

Comment: @Toleo `CONCAT` will combine multiple values into a single cell, `JOIN` will combine multiple tables into a single row.  You could have a `JOIN` query and also use `CONCAT`, or vice versa, but they each perform distinct tasks.